# Problem when deleting ImageField from database

Tags: python, django

models.py:

```
Picture = models.ImageField('Picture', null=True, blank=True)
```

When I give the command

```
person.Picture.delete()
```

the picture is deleted from the directory, but in the database still has the record of the file path in Picture as shown in image below. How can I delete it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to try

```
person = Person.objects.get(User=User_) 
person.Picture.delete(save=False)
...
person.save()
```

Try setting the path in your model something like below

```
Picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='Picture', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Not working, I don't know why

Comment: with save set to True ?

Comment: yes. It continues with the path in database.

Comment: I'm trying: person = Person.objects.get(User=User_)
    person.Picture.delete(save=False)
    person.save()

Comment: person = Person.objects.get(User=User_) 
person.Picture.delete(save=False)
person.Picture=None
person.save() not worked too

Comment: the path is not deleted.. I really don't know why

Comment: @searcher__dm01 please check the updated answer

Comment: Not working yet

Comment: Is there any way to access the path and delete it? Something like Picture.path?

Comment: Picture.path is a read only object

Comment: It should have worked. Just try refreshing the admin page ctrl + f5

Comment: I really don't know why

Comment: The most crazy thing is that when I run dubuggind the code in PyCharm it works.. bur in normal mode not works

Answer (score 1):

Set the field to `None` as well, so:

```
person.Picture.delete()
person.Picture = None
person.save()
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `picture` instead of <s>`Picture`</s>.

Comment: Not worked. I don't know why.. I tried save=False too